# England: Alternative to Student Finance

Tags: united-kingdom, student-loan

I am currently considering a change of course at my current University, but as I have already just started my second year of study, I won't be entitled to one years tuition fee loan from Student Finance England.

The only option that I can find aimed at students as an alternative to the government student finance is this: https://www.financemyfuture.co.uk

I was wondering if anyone knows of any other services like the above, so that I can compare the options, or if anyone can think of an alternative way to fund one years tuition fee

Answer (score 1):

Since you're also looking for alternative means of funding, have you considered doing part-time work -- during the holidays or on some of the weekends?

With this kind of financing you have to watch out that the work does not interfere with your study. On the other hand it can be valuable work experience that can come in handy later in your life, such as when applying for your first "real" job.

The kind of work you can do will depend a lot on the subject you are studying and what qualifications you have. For example, if you are studying computer science, there are a lot of freelance opportunities in programming. One of these could lead right to your first job after university.

The two broad types of work you can do are:

- Freelance
- Employment

For freelance: Try searching for "[subject] student freelance" and look at sites like oDesk. Read up on tax concerns, research how to price your time, and start doing!

For employment: Browse the job boards at your university. Contact businesses to ask for part-time opportunities.

Hope this helps to open one of the alternative paths here. If you go down this road, remember to keep your priorities in mind. Especially the freelance work can easily interfere with your study and delay you unnecessarily.

Good luck!

Comment: A part time job is unlikely to unable to finance the cost of £9000 this is a bad and pious answer that doesn't really understand the OP's Q

Comment: @Pepone 9k GBP is under 12k EUR. That's 1k EUR/mo, coverable with a qualified part time job. Reasonable freelance rates in software development, without formal qualification, will cover this in two to three weekends per month, with buffer for UK taxes/insurance (which I admit I do not know v/ well). Also keep this in mind: "The kind of work you can do will depend a lot on the subject you are studying and what qualifications you have." If the work available to the OP does not pay well enough they might also consider a combination of paid work with other sources of financing.